# Plot a neural network layer diagram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I hope you are doing well. I am currently examining a simple neural network.

My neural network has one layer and only one neuron, where the inputs are multiplied by weights and summed together in the following form:
w1x1 + w2x2 + b

I have randomly initialized the values of w, x, and b. However, I wanted to plot this line using matplotlib.

The issue I'm facing is that I have two inputs, and ultimately this equation yields one output. When plotting the graph, I don't know which input to consider as the x-axis and which as the y-axis.

w1 and w2 are numbers, as well as x1 and x2.

This my code.
`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random weights and bias
w1 = np.random.randint(0, 100)
w2 = np.random.randint(0, 100)
b = np.random.randint(2000, 10000)

# Generate input data
x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

# Generate weights
w = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2,))

# Calculate network output for each input point
y = w[0] * x1 + w[1] * x2 + b

plt.plot(x1, y, label='Line formed by weights and bias')
plt.xlabel('Input variable x1')
plt.ylabel('Network output')
plt.title('Plot of line formed by weights and bias')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Changing the code to draw a graph representing the equation of a line correctly.

Comment: "When plotting the graph, I don't know which input to consider as the x-axis and which as the y-axis." If you plot x1 as the x axis, and y as the y axis, you will not get a straight line, only series of points with an upward trend. Similarly, if you plot x2 as the x axis, and y as the y axis, you will also not get a straight line. Hypothetically, you could hold x2 constant, and plot x1 vs y, and get a straight line.

Comment: I don't understand what the goal is. What is the plot intended to show? Why is it important that the result be a straight line?

Comment: Consider if you keep x2 constant and plot x1 against y, you can obtain a line. Can you modify its code and provide it, because I didn't quite understand what you meant?

Comment: @Nick ODellAccording to what has been requested, a line should be plotted.

Comment: Example of holding x2 constant: https://gist.github.com/nickodell/1c69290f33cfe5cc87480b88944e3d63

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
However, you input x1 at line 18 in the code,
But we have two inputs and we cannot obtain results in this way.

Can we ultimately understand that it is not possible to draw a line with two inputs x1 and x2 in two-dimensional space?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. You need a [surface plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function#Functions_of_two_variables) to visualize a plot of two variables.